# Getting current map scale in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, scale

I'm trying to get the current map scale in PyQGIS, running outside QGIS, with:

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
root = project.layerTreeRoot()
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(root, canvas)
# project.read(projectpath)
canvas.center()
canvas.extent()
canvas.scale()
```

The center and the extent are just perfect! But the scale is quite different from the one reported at QGIS bottom bar.

Testing the same in QGIS gives the same result.

How do I get the current map scale in PyQGIS (3.x)?

I'm using a project coordinate system, using meters.

[image: example]

Comment: `iface.mapCanvas().scale()` works in Python console.

Comment: I've followed the documentation https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadproject.html?highlight=standalone

Comment: Are the canvases different sizes? Try iface.mapCanvas().size() in the python console and canvas.size() and see if you get the same result.

Answer (score 5):

You need the canvas to be the same size for the scale to be the same.

Here is the small fragment of code

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
root = project.layerTreeRoot()
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(root, canvas)

canvas.setExtent(iface.mapCanvas().extent())
canvas.setCenter(iface.mapCanvas().center())
canvas.resize(iface.mapCanvas().size())

canvas.show()
canvas.scale()
#canvas.hide()
```

[image]

Comment: Something if not working on my side (QGIS 3.11.0-Master. `iface.mapCanvas().scale()` works pretty well, but using another canvas with the same extend, center and size fails: `canvas.scale() = 9353194300.573679`.

Comment: Something strange is going on in QGIS 3.4.12 too. If I use the commands in the answer posted above I get a canvas.scale of  765592971.6097143 when my project has a scale of 10,000. If I set the scale of the canvas to iface.mapCanvas().scale() (ie 10,000) canvas.scale() reports the correct scale, but the extent is no longer correct!

Comment: It's strange but using show() and after hide() also happens?

Comment: Yes, if I run canvas.scale() before show() and hide() I get 1141189523.5122857 and after show() and hide() 765592971.6097143. So show and hide changes the reported scale but unfortunately doesn't make it produce the expected answer